# Can't upload or download files into database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project, and I am trying to upload files into my database and displaying their URL so I can download them again. But when I press upload, I get an error in the index view referring to this line

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

Error Message:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. AspNetCore.Views_Demo_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml, line 25 @foreach (var item in Model)
```

Here is my model class:

```
public class Files
{
    [Key]
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public byte[] DataFiles { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
using Info.Data;
using Info.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Info.Controllers
{
    public class DemoController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public DemoController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var result = _context.Files.ToList();
            return View(result);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(IFormFile files)
        {
            if (files != null)
            {
                if (files.Length > 0)
                {
                    //Getting FileName
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(files.FileName);
                    //Getting file Extension
                    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                    // concatenating  FileName + FileExtension
                    var newFileName = String.Concat(Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid()), fileExtension);

                    var objfiles = new Files()
                    {
                        DocumentId = 0,
                        Name = newFileName,
                        FileType = fileExtension,
                    };

                    using (var target = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        files.CopyTo(target);
                        objfiles.DataFiles = target.ToArray();
                    }

                    _context.Files.Add(objfiles);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult DownloadImage(int id)
        {
            byte[] bytes;
            string fileName, contentType;

            var item = _context.Files.FirstOrDefault(c => c.DocumentId == id);

            if (item != null)
            {
                fileName = item.Name;

                contentType = item.FileType;
                bytes = item.DataFiles;

                return File(bytes, contentType, fileName);
            }

            return Ok("Can't find the File");
        }      
    }
}
```

Here is the view

```
@model List<Info.Models.Files>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Demo" asp-action="Index">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <p>Upload file</p>
                    <input class="form-control" name="files" type="file" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Upload" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <a asp-action="DownloadImage"
               asp-route-filename="@item.Name">
                @item.Name
            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

I can't upload or download.

Comment: You tagged this as both asp.net and asp.net-core. Those are different frameworks. Make sure you pick the one you're actually using. And note that if you're using ASP.NET Core, then the asp.net-mvc-4 wouldn't be relevant, and it also wouldn't be relevant if you're actually using ASP.NET MVC 5. Please edit your question appropriately, and make sure you put some thought into the tags as it lets people know what framework you're using and helps attract the right people to look at your question. Based on the code, you're using ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET Core MVC so I've edited your tags appropriately

Comment: You mentioned you're getting an error, but you haven't included that in your question. Please don't make people guess: give full error details in your question. Please edit that in.

Comment: please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question

Comment: Is there an error/exception? If so include it. Is there anything else, like: the bytearray not being stored in database? Include the full details in the question, we can't guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hhaannyy.

Your index view code is:

```
@model List<Info.Models.Files>
 ...............

<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <a asp-action="DownloadImage"
               asp-route-filename="@item.Name">
                @item.Name
            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

When you load your index view, You need to pass a list of `Info.Models.Files`  from controller to view and use `@foreach(xxx)` to show them right?

In your get action, you use:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
      var result = _context.Files.ToList();
      return View(result);
}
```

to pass `_context.Files.ToList();` to the view, `@foreach(xxx)` can work successfully. But in your `HttpPost` action, After you upload file and save it in db, you just `return View();`, You don't pass any value to the view, The model is null in your View, So `@foreach (var item in Model)` will show NullReferenceException. You can use this code to solve this error:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(IFormFile files)
    {
        //...............

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: My dear thank you so much this is worked for me but the download gives me Can't find the File any way many thanks for you , i will check for download